# get <sqlite3.Connection> on <sqlalchemy.engine.base.Connection>

Tags: sqlite, sqlalchemy

Is there a way to retrieve <sqlite3.Connection> object given the corresponding/wrapping <sqlalchemy.engine.base.Connection> object?

What exactly is their relationship? Can't find it in documentation.

Comment: `cnxn = engine.raw_connection()`

Comment: What's the actual use case?

Comment: @llja Everlia For comparison use case my friend. If you want to keep track of all different connections produced by different threads, you want to log each of those connection objects.

Comment: @GordThompson No that method I have seen in the documentation and already tried. It only gives you sqlalchemy's connection, not sqlite3 connection object.

Comment: Hmm, how about `cnxn = engine.raw_connection().connection` …?

Comment: @GordThompson This works! If you have the time making this your official answer, I will adopt it. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases when working with a "raw" DBAPI connection it is sufficient to use `.raw_connection()`. The resulting object is able to make use of DBAPI-specific methods and attributes, but it is actually a SQLAlchemy "wrapper" around the connection object

```
>>> import sqlalchemy as sa
>>> engine = sa.create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:")
>>> engine.raw_connection()
<sqlalchemy.pool.base._ConnectionFairy object at 0x0000001639B40F48>
```

To retrieve the actual DBAPI connection object we need to use the `.connection` attribute of that "wrapper" object:

```
>>> engine.raw_connection().connection
<sqlite3.Connection object at 0x0000001639B14490>
```